# Storing bitmap into sql

Tags: vb.net, image, storage

I'm coding an app for printing bills. I have a form within I load data. I  want to automate printing, so in that order i save a bmp image of my filled form and then store into a mdf database for late print each row/cell (images in this case). But when i drag my table into a preview form (just for chek if i store data correctly) the id of each row appears, but i can't see that row's image... the question is: what am i doing wrong here? (i watched a lot o tutorials for last 3 days but i can't figure out yet what to do)

```
Public Sub toBitMap()
  'Define un nuevo bitmap con las dimensiones del form  
  Dim miBitMap As New Bitmap(imprimir.Width, imprimir.Height)
  ' Dibuja la imagen del form en un objetoBitmap
  imprimir.DrawToBitmap(miBitMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, imprimir.Width, imprimir.Height))
  Dim memoryStreamBuffer = New MemoryStream()
  miBitMap.Save(memoryStreamBuffer, ImageFormat.Bmp)
  Dim data As Byte() = memoryStreamBuffer.GetBuffer()
  Dim saveImage As imagenesTableAdapter = New imagenesTableAdapter
  Dim a As String = saveImage.insertImagen(data)
  If multiple.iteraciones <= 0 Then
    cantidad = saveImage.ScalarQuery()
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You arent going to see an image in the Access DB, you are storing the bytes.  There is a lot wrong there, a BMP is huge so consider a JPG, consider saving just a filename to the MDF and the actual file to avoid bloating the DB, dispose of your memstream and dont use GetBuffer.  There are many many examples here how to do this

Comment: Thanks a lot.i'm lookin for info about your advices Do you suggest another approach to do automatic printing? Gjc

Comment: Please **avoid inflating big BLOBs of data** in a such a limited database as Access is. You'd better store the images on the File System, and store the **paths** (strings) in the database.

Comment: Wheel, i din't mention that i'll store images just for printing, after thath i clean up my db. It's an SQL mdf database (created from vb). Now i'm planing to save tmp paths and print my form's image JPG formatted.

Comment: FYI - no need to edit in things like `[Solved]` into your questions here on Stack Overflow - just accept an answer (when you're able) - that's indication enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Der Golem and @Lars Tech (Plutonix) for your nice answers. I'have achieved half of my goal in this way:

```
    Public Sub toBitMap(ByVal indice)
    'Define un nuevo bitmap con las dimensiones del form  
    Dim miBitMap As New Bitmap(imprimir.Width, imprimir.Height)
    ' Dibuja la imagen del form en un objetoBitmap
    imprimir.DrawToBitmap(miBitMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, imprimir.Width, imprimir.Height))
    'definicion de nombre y path para archivos temporales
    Dim tempImageName As String = "tmp" & indice & ".png"
    Dim tmpImageAbsolutePath As String = Application.StartupPath & _  
    "\data\" & tempImageName
    'Creacion de nuevo png
    miBitMap.Save(tmpImageAbsolutePath, ImageFormat.Png)
    'Carga de paths a la base
    Dim saveImage As imagenesTableAdapter = New imagenesTableAdapter
    Dim a As String = saveImage.Insert(tempImageName)
    If indice <= 1 Then
        cantidad = saveImage.ScalarQuery()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I just clean the tmp folder and db.

**Just need to know how to take those files (pics) into a pdf for printing, but  I have google! :D